# GameObject (Stuck At Screen Edge) In Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Classic Stacker game that the ice cream should go across the screen.
It works and moves the object but sometimes it gets stuck on the sides of the screen like this

[image]

Here is the code

```
private float min_X = -2.48f, max_X = 2.48f;
private float move_Speed = 60f;
  void Start()
    {
        GamePlayController.instance.currentBox = this;
        canMove =true;

        if (Random.Range(0, 2) > 0){
            move_Speed *= -1f;
        }
       
    }

 void MoveBox(){

        if (canMove)
        {
            Vector3 temp = transform.position;
            if (temp.x > max_X)
            {
                move_Speed *= -1f;
            }
            else if (temp.x < min_X)
            {
                move_Speed *= -1f;
            }

            temp.x += move_Speed * Time.deltaTime;

   


            transform.position = temp;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to only flip the direction once when it reaches the edge. Currently you could be flipping it back and forth every frame once it is above or below the max and it would never get back inside the range

Something like this should work

```
private float min_X = -2.48f, max_X = 2.48f;
private float move_Speed = 60f;
private int direction = 1;
  void Start()
    {
        GamePlayController.instance.currentBox = this;
        canMove =true;

        if (Random.Range(0, 2) > 0){
            direction *= -1f;
        }
       
    }
void MoveBox(){

        if (canMove)
        {
            Vector3 temp = transform.position;


            if (temp.x > max_X)
            {
                direction = -1f;
            }
            else if (temp.x < min_X)
            {
                direction = 1f;
            }

            temp.x += move_Speed * Time.deltaTime * direction;  


            transform.position = temp;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just tired it, the icecream just stay in one place moving a little. the code i have moves how i want just sometimes get stuck on the edges

Comment: That's what I get for answering on my phone at 1am :). Just needed to move the direction variable to a class variable instead of local, and initialize it with your random value.